# Cannot set listiview's setchoice mode to multiple choice mode

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am not able to set the choice mode of my listview to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE.

I have set the the choice mode to multiple like this:

```
lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

but since I am using a custom layout for the rows of my listview, that's why perhaps I am facing this problem.

```
ListViewHomeAdapter adapter = new ListViewHomeAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row,listViewHomeData);
```

Does anybody have a solution?

Here goes the code for ListViewHomeAdapter.java

public class ListViewHomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ListViewHome data[] = null;

public ListViewHomeAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ListViewHome[] data)
{
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);

    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.data = data;       
}

@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    ListViewHomeHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ListViewHomeHolder();

        holder.DocName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        holder.CreationDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);

        row.setTag(holder);
        row.setMinimumHeight(20);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ListViewHomeHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    ListViewHome listviewhome = data[position];
    holder.DocName.setText(listviewhome.DocName);
    holder.CreationDate.setText(listviewhome.CreationDate);

    return row;
}

static class ListViewHomeHolder
{
    TextView DocName;
    TextView CreationDate;
}
```

}

Comment: post the code of ListViewHomeAdapter  and when you init the ListView

Comment: Have edited my post with the ListViewHomeAdapter code.